# Reading multiple lines in C using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

i'm currently doing an uni project which has to read a multiple lines sequence of inputs given in a .txt format. This is my first experience with C, so i don't know much about reading files with fscanf and then processing them. The code i wrote goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char tipo [1];
    float n1, n2, n3, n4;
    int i;
    FILE *stream;
    stream=fopen("init.txt", "r");
    if ((stream=fopen("init.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error");
    } else {
        i=0;
        while (i<4) {
            i++;
//i know i could use a for instead of a while
            fscanf(stream, "%s %f %f %f %f%", &tipo, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
            printf("%s %f %f %f %f", tipo, n1, n2, n3, n4);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My "init" file is formatted like this:

```
L 150.50 165.18 182.16 200.50
G 768.12 876.27 976.56 958.12
A 1250.15 1252.55 1260.60 1265.15
L 200.50 245.30 260.10 275.00
A 1450.15 1523.54 1245.17 1278.23
G 958.12 1000.65 1040.78 1068.12
```

I don't know how to *tell* the program to skip a line after the first one is read.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Passing the value of `&tipo` as the first argument is bad in 2 ways: you're passing a pointer to array of 1 char, but `%s` expects a pointer to char pointing to 1st char of a buffer with enough space to read a string of non-whitespace characters. A string in C is null-terminated, so in your case 2 characters are written, but your array has space for 1.

Comment: I assume your code does not work. Explain how.

Comment: In general, avoid using `scanf` or `fscanf`.  They're notoriously hard to use.  Read each line one at a time with `fgets` and then you can use `sscanf` on each resulting string.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. Is this your desired output?L 150.50 165.18 182.16 200.50
A 1250.15 1252.55 1260.60 1265.15
A 1450.15 1523.54 1245.17 1278.23

Comment: I'd argue that `fscanf` is *notoriously hard to use*. It's easy as hell. [Don't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use a char array (string) when you're only going to read one character.

Do this:

```
char tipo;
```

and

```
fscanf(stream, " %c %f %f %f %f%", &tipo, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
```

and your code should work. Note the `c` instead of s.

Comment: Note that this will read the newline into `tipo` after the first use (unless you take steps to read up to and including the newline).  You might be better off using `" %c …"` where the space before the `%c` skips zero or more white space characters — such as blank, tab, and newline.  However, you don't have control over `fscanf()` skipping blank lines this way.  If you care about that, don't use `fscanf()` at all — read the lines with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and then use `sscanf()` to parse the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fscanf(stream, "%*[^\n]\n")` to skip line. Just add one `if` statement to check line number to skip. `if (i == 2)` to skip second line.
Also change `char tipo[1]` to `char tipo` and change "%s" to "%c" in `printf` and `fscanf`

```
while (i++ < 4) 
{
    if (i == 2) // checks line number. Skip 2-nd line
    {
        fscanf(stream, "%*[^\n]\n");
    }
    fscanf(stream, "%c %f %f %f %f\n", &tipo, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
    printf("%c %f %f %f %f\n", tipo, n1, n2, n3, n4);
}
```

Also you are opening file twice. `if(streem = fopen("init.txt", "r") == NULL)` will be true because you have already opened file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, particularly with the fopen == null one. Since i'm a newbie, i didn't know that

Comment: Just remove stream=fopen(“init.txt”,”r”) because you are opening file twice. You don’t need it.

Comment: Note [the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168).  It is mostly OK if the input will always be a disk file, but it is diabolically awful if a human might ever do the typing.

Answer (score 1):

In response to "*I don't know how to tell the program to skip a line after the first one is read*."Just do this!

```
while (i<4) 
{
    i++;
    //i know i could use a for instead of a while
    fscanf(stream, "%s %f %f %f %f%", &tipo, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
    if(i != 2) //skipping second line
        printf("%s %f %f %f %f", tipo, n1, n2, n3, n4);

}
```

Also there is no point in using an 1-element array. If you wish to just use a `char` element change it from `char tipo [1];` to `char tipo;` and your respective `"%s"` to `"%c"`. But if you wish it to be a `string` element : change it from `char tipo [1];` to `char *tipo;` or `char tipo [n];` and keep your `"%s"`.

Comment: Yeah, i don't need to have a string, so this helped me!